# .htaccess mod_rewrite change link URL

Tags: .htaccess

What I have is a link:

```
www.example.com/?ref=ID
```

What I am trying to do, is to make this link to look and work like this:

```
www.example.com/ref-ID
```

Note that `ID` is different each time, since new users generate new accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ref-([0-9]+)$ /index.php?ref=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Using `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`, in a nutshell.

Essentially that just checks that the requested URL is **not** a file or directory; extracts the number after `ref-` (assuming that's something like an auto-incremented integer) and passes that to index.php via a `ref` parameter.